# Convert syslog-ng to rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog

How can I convert this configuration to rsyslog?

```
options {
        long_hostnames(off);
        sync(0);
        perm(0640);
        stats(3600);
        log_msg_size(163840);
        log_fifo_size(50000);
};

source s_local {
        unix-dgram("/dev/log");
        file("/proc/kmsg" log_prefix("kernel:"));
};
```

I'm migrating to rsyslog 7.4 and can't find anywhere in the official documentation how to set those settings or listening for an unix-dgram.

Comment: Hi, may I ask why are you migrating to rsyslog? I am the documentation maintainer of syslog-ng, and would be really interested in your experiences that made you want to switch to rsyslog.

Comment: It's actually a standard in my company. All servers with syslog-ng are being switched to rsyslog. Thanks for your interest, and congratulations for the documentation. It's much better than rsyslog's.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and also thank you for taking time to reply :)

Comment: I wanted to share my experiences with you Robert, we're switching because newer versions of Ubuntu ship with rsyslog. Just wanted to let you know.